# How to know if a vector is composed by the same elements?

Tags: r, vector, unique

How can I check if a vector has all the same elements?

For example let's say I have:

```
vec1 = rep(10,20)
vec2 = seq(1:20)
```

How can I show that `vec1` has all the same elements?

Comment: `diff(vec1)` returns what?

Comment: or one `unique` element

Comment: @rawr answer as code `length(unique(vec1)) == 1`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An option is `diff`.

```
diff(vec1)
```

If the elements are equal, their difference is zero.

```
all(diff(vec1) == 0)
#[1] TRUE
```

Or compare the vector to its first element.

```
all(vec1 == vec1[1])
#[1] TRUE
```

## Edit.

Several ways of determining if all elements of a vector are equal were posted, see [RHertel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60477414/8245406), [Yuriy Saraykin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60477483/8245406), [tmfmnk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60477581/8245406). Here are comparative tests.

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(ggplot2)

f <- function(n){
  x <- rep(10, n)
  mb <- microbenchmark(
    var = var(x) == 0,
    sd = sd(x) == 0,
    diff = all(diff(x) == 0),
    extract = all(x == x[1]),
    unique = length(unique(x)) == 1
  )
  mb
}

sizes <- c(10, 100, seq(1e3, 1e4, by = 1e3))
mb_list <- lapply(sizes, f)
names(mb_list) <- sizes

res <- lapply(seq_along(mb_list), function(i){
  agg <- aggregate(time ~ expr, mb_list[[i]], median)
  agg$size <- sizes[i]
  agg
})
res <- do.call(rbind, res)

ggplot(res, aes(size, time, colour = expr)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Use the variance. If all elements of a vector are equal, the variance is zero:

```
allElementsEqual <- function(x) {!var(x)}

#allElementsEqual(vec1)
#[1] TRUE
#allElementsEqual(vec2)
#[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 4):

count the number of unique values

```
length(unique(vec1))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also calculate the standard deviation and assess whether it is zero:

```
sd(vec1) == 0

[1] TRUE
```

Or using `table()`:

```
length(table(vec1)) == 1
```

Or using `rle()`:

```
length(rle(vec1)$lengths) == 1
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `n_distinct` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
n_distinct(vec1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it into a factor and get the levels which should be only 1 value if they are all same.

```
vec1 <- (10,20)

vec <- factor(vec1)

levels(vec)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another quick/efficient option for numeric vectors is to use `max() == min()`. I.e., if the max value is equal to the minimum value (`na.rm = FALSE` by default), all elements are equal:

```
vec1 = rep(10,20)
vec2 = seq(1:20)

max(vec1) == min(vec1)
[1] TRUE
max(vec2) == min(vec2)
[1] FALSE
```

EDIT: note, if there are possibly `NA`'s this will need adaption to treat it as-needed. Also, side-note, the memory allocation is very low on my machine (I tested on vectors up to 1e8 and it remained at zero).